# Manipulate Lucene query before performing search

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'm working on a Java webapp (Spring 3.x) that uses SOLR for its search engine. I want to be able to intercept the Lucene query and substitute a "virtual" search field for either one of two indexed fields, based upon a lookup service (if successful use a range search otherwise search a regular field).

E.g., given a query like `field0:foo (field1:bar OR field1:bash) AND field2:bing` (field1 being a virtual field)

manipulate the query to get `field0:foo (field3:[42 TO 45] OR field4:bash) AND field2:bing`

So after toying with the idea of just using a reg ex, I decided to look at the Lucene classes, to see if I could re-use existing code. I'd like to be able to get a parsed version of the query so as to iterate over the clauses, looking for certain fields to manipulate. Then re-generate the query string and pass it on to SOLR.

I've got close using Lucene's [QueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html) but I can only get the terms and not the boolean operators:

```
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "text", analyzer);
try {
    Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString);
    Set<Term> terms = new TreeSet<Term>();
    query.extractTerms(terms);

    for (Term t : terms) {
        logger.info("Term - field:" + t.field() + " | text:" + t.text());
    }
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    logger.warn(ex.getMessage(), ex);
}
```

I've looked at the [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) but haven't had luck there either. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your own query parser:

```
class MyParser : MultiFieldQueryParser {
  @override
  public Query getFieldQuery(string field, string queryText) {
     if lookupSuccessful(field, queryText) { 
       return myQuery(field, queryText);
     }
     return base.getFieldQuery(field, queryText);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why extend MultiFieldQueryParser vs QueryParser? They both implement a getFieldQuery() method...

Comment: @nickdos: I personally use a `MultiFieldQueryParser` so that's what I put. You can of course use a normal one if that's what you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Xodarap, I wasn't sure about your answer at first (didn't know how getFieldQuery() was called by Lucene). But gave it a go and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I think I ticked too soon - it appears the parsed Query.toString() outputs a version of the Lucene query syntax that assumes the default operator is OR, even when I set it to AND via QueryParser.setDefaultOperator(). I.e. the defaultOperator is used when parsing the query but not when producing the String version. E.g. input query `(f1:cat OR f1:dog) AND f2:cow AND f3:"tree frog"` when parsed, gives `(f1:cat f1:dog) +f2:cow +f3:"tree frog"`. The SOLR config has AND as default operator and thus ANDs the f1 terms. I haven't come up with a work-around short of changing my service to assume an OR.

Comment: @nickdos: interesting. Can't really help you, I've never tried to change the default operator myself, sorry. Might be worth asking another question.

Comment: Yes, its a separate issue really - will keep your answer as correct. Will do a bit more investigating before asking a new SO Q.

Comment: Started separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205287/lucene-queryparser-produce-a-portable-query-to-send-to-solr