# Lucene QueryParser - produce a "portable" query to send to SOLR

Tags: solr, lucene

Following on from my earlier question:

[Manipulate Lucene query before performing search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8178795/manipulate-lucene-query-before-performing-search)

I've run into a problem where I'm wanting to send a `QueryParser` parsed `Query` (`Query.toString()`) onto a webservice that uses SOLR with a default operator of `AND`. Because Lucene has `OR` as its default operator any OR'ed terms are left "as is". E.g. given the query:

```
(f1:cat OR f1:dog) AND f2:cow AND f3:"tree frog"
```

once parsed (with `QuerParser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.AND)`), the String version becomes:

```
+(f1:cat f1:dog) +f2:cow +f3:"tree frog"
```

When this is passed to SOLR, with an assumed `AND` operator, the two f1 terms get AND'ed instead of OR'ed.

The only work-around I can think of is to change my SOLR installation to use OR as its default Boolean operator... Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default operator can be overriden on a per-request basis. For exemple :

Using params: `http://solr/select?q=query&q.op=OR`

Or using local params: `http://solr/select?q={!lucene q.op=OR}query`

See [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that. I actually read through the SolrQuerySyntax page before posting but missed the `q.op=AND` snippet in there.

Comment: This answer does overcome my problem but is not as useful to me as I'd wish. My webservice sanitizes the search query before passing it onto SOLR so I'm going to have to make changes to it to be able to use one of these params, unfortunately. I'm frustrated that the original Boolean query is unambiguous and not dependent on a default operator and that I loose this "unambiguousness" when it gets parsed. Oh well...